# NodeJS Socket.io Sticky-Session missing headers

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-headers

**Short Description**
Using clusters in NodeJS -> net.createServer -> Socket.IO, how can I get headers or connection string before sending to worker?

**Long Description**
I'm having 4 servers running with 8 CPUs each. With load balancer and cluster I will get 32 nodes + 4 master nodes.

The load balancer will use ip address to determine to what server it will use. Running Unity Socket.IO else I would like to use JSESSIONID. When the connection comes to the master node it looks on the ip to determine what cluster to use.

Here I really want to use something else or all connections (or most) will be on same cluster. So using connection string unique id or cookie.

When connecting I'm adding a unique value to the connection string ?unique={guid} however when reaching the master node I can't get this data (or cookies / headers).

```
// THIS IS MASTER NODE

var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function (connection) {

    // HOW TO GET headers or URL from connection?

    // Incoming request processing
    var remote = connection.remoteAddress;
    var local = connection.localAddress;
    var cIp = remote + local;
    var ip = cIp.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0].replace(/,/g, '');
    var wIndex = ip % num_processes;

    // here we get the worker
    var worker = workers[wIndex];

    logger.log("Message to work "+ worker+", remote: "+ remote+ ", local: "+ local+", ip: "+ ip +", index: "+ wIndex);
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);

});


// THIS IS A WORKER NODE

process.on('message', function(message, connection) {
    if (message !== 'sticky-session:connection') {
        return;
    }

    // Emulate a connection event on the server by emitting the
    // event with the connection the master sent us.
    http.emit('connection', connection);

    connection.resume();
});
```

I've tried to capture information in 'data' but then the chat stops working.

```
connection.on('data', function (data) {

    /* WHERE I GET OUTPUT OF 

    GET /chat HTTP/1.1
    Host: 127.0.0.1:5223
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
    */
    console.log(data.toString('utf8', 0, data.length));


    // BUT THE CHAT WONT WORK
});
```

Comment: When using pauseOnConnect you cannot get the data.